# Nested probability

Tags: probability

One of three items is given to a user based on probability. Chance of giving item $a = 7/10$, $b = 2/10$ and $c = 1/10$. After that, there is $1/4$ chance of repeating the first step.

As algorithm:

1. $n$ = random number between $1\dots10$
2. $n \le 7 \rightarrow$ give item $a$, else $n \le 9 \rightarrow$ give item $b$, else give item $c$
3. $m$ = random number between $1\dots 4$
4. $m \ge 3 \rightarrow$ repeat steps $1$ and $2$
5. end

I need to figure out what's the chance of user getting item $a$ at least once. To clarify, if step two is repeated, program is then terminated, so step two can be reapeated only once (it's not a jump). If there wouldn't be step $4$, the chance would be $7/10$.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! According to your description at the end, we get at most 2 items, right? In this case, what is the probability that you don't get $a$? That is, you either get one of $b$ and $c$ and terminate, or get one of these and not terminate, only to get one of $b$ and $c$ again?

Comment: By the way, the algorithm doesn't accurately represent what you wrote below. What it does describe is something that may not terminate. This would actually be the interesting case to compute, we would get an infinite geometric sum that converges.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Ekin, i'm acually coming for an advice from SO, been user there for some time. Right, you can get 2 items max. The program will always terminate (I might have not put that correctly). "That is, you either get one of b
 and c
 and terminate, or get one of these and not terminate, only to get one of b
 and c
 again?" --> You get 1 a, b or c. If then program decides to repeat steps 1 and 2, another random number is generated and you get 1 a, b or c again. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: So, just to clarify, are you saying that there is a $\frac 14$ chance of automatically repeating and a $\frac 34$ chance of drawing anew, in which case you might end up repeating anyway?  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: There is 1/4 chance of repeating but this repeat can occur only once. This is actually problem from a "real life" application I'm working on, not a theory question so it's meant in the simple way - whether a, b, or c is given to user on first pass doesn't matter. After that with 1/4 chance [a new random number for deciding on giving a, b, or c will be generated and and that number is used to give user a, b or c] put that into parenthesis to emphasize on all of that happening if 1/4 chance check is met.

Comment: To stress:  your pseudocode is not helpful.  It appears to say that you  repeat with probability $\frac 12$, since $m≥3$ represents half the cases amongst $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  And your code loops forever, there is nothing that terminates in it.  Having that code in your post confuses the question enormously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is poorly phrased, but whatever the rules are it should be easy enough to answer it explicitly.

First note that the distinction between $b$ and $c$ appears to be irrelevant.  All that matters is that they are "not $a$".  Thus we let $X$ be "not $a$" and note that you get $a$ with probability $.7$ and $X$ with probability $.3$

Assuming the question is:  "draw once with the given probabilities.  Then, with probability $.75$ you terminate the game and with probability $.25$ you draw one more time with the same probabilities and then terminate.  What is the probability that you get $a$ at least once?"

Now, the ways to get an $a$ are either:

I. get $a$ first ($.7$).  After that it makes no difference what happens.

II.  get $X$ first ($.3$) and then repeat ($.25$) and draw an $a$ ($.7$).  Thus the probability of this path is $.3\times .25\times .7=.0525$

Finally the answer is the sum $$.7+.0525=\boxed {.7525}$$

Answer (score 1):

Again for clarity, you get at most 2 items from the algorithm. Also, the probability of repetition is $\frac{1}{4}$ and not $\frac{1}{2}$ as indicated in the algorithm.

We calculate the probability that you do not get $a$ at all, and we will subtract this from 1 at the end.
$P(\text{no $a$})=P(\text{no $a$ | one item given})+P(\text{no $a$ | two items given}) = \frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{10}=\frac{99}{400}$.

So the answer should be $\frac{301}{400}$, if I am not mistaken. But then again, infinite repetitions would be more fun.

Comment: Thanks for the patience with my question and guidance. Upvoting, but I'm marking lulu's question as accepted, hence his/hers explanation is easier for me to understand.